# Error function property

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I have a question regarding a property of the error function.

Is $k\cdot\text{erfc}(-x) = 1-k\cdot\text{erfc}(x)$ for all real $x$ for any $k$?

Comment: I made a mistake in defining the issue,so my real issue is this:
I got the answer for a aprticular problem as 1-erfc(3/(2^1.5)) while the answer i got in my book is 1/2{erfc(-3/(2^1.5))}-1/2{erfc(3/(2^1.5))}    Are they same?

Comment: Could you clarify ?

Comment: For a normal distribution having mean =1.6 and variance=0.4, I need to find p{-0.6<X-1.6<=0.6}: I tried it by doing integration from -∞ to -6 and other one 1-(6 to ∞) i got answer as1-erfc(3/(2^1.5))(i put x-1.6 as my variable in integration) but in my book it is done like for p{1<X<=2.2} and they got  1/2{erfc(-3/(2^1.5))}-1/2{erfc(3/(2^1.5))}, I can check if they both are equal or not, but i do not know the erfc of a negative number..........can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this cannot be true, because for $k=0$ this would yield $0=1$.

Your comment suggest however that you are interested in the equality:
$$
1-\text{erfc}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{erfc}(-x)-\text{erfc}(x)\right)
$$
This is indeed true, because
$$1-\text{erfc}(x) = \text{erf}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{erf}(x)-\text{erf}(-x))\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{erfc}(-x)-\text{erfc}(x)\right)$$

Here I made use of the definition of $\text{erfc}$ and the anti-symmetry of $\text{erf}$.

Comment: thanks that solved it, further i got to know : erf(x)=1/2(erf(x)−erf(−x))), which i was not aware of thanks :)

Comment: This is true simply because -erf(x) = erf(-x).

Comment: yep, anti symmetric got it :)